# How to find the Lihzahrd temple in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I have been looking all over my jungle in Terraria and I can't seem to find the Lihzahrd temple anywhere. Does anyone have any tips on how to find it?

Answer (score 5):

The [Jungle Temple](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Temple) is randomly generated somewhere within the Underground Jungle biome. There is not specific ways for finding it.

Note that it can generate on the very edge of the underground jungle, so make sure you have explored the **entire** jungle to its edges.

If you are still having no luck, you could download a [map viewer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Map_viewers) to pinpoint the location of your temple.

Comment: The Jungle Temple is ruffly the same depth so you dont need to digg all the way down to the underworld